# Trim all occurences of a character in PostgreSql

Tags: sql, postgresql, trim

I am trying to remove all the zeros from the values of the attribute `salary`.
I am using `TRIM` function (by typecasting `salary` into `TEXT`). `TRIM` function does not remove 0s that are in between, for example, if I use it on `809800` the result is `'8098'`. The `'0'` in the middle is still there.
Here is what I am doing:

[image: PostgreSql]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: check out `replace()`

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike, it works. That was some quick reply. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `replace()` for that:

[demo:db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=a1964f253c9dcdea5b547e85c7f872e0)

```
SELECT replace('01000200330004000', '0', '')
```

or for using with your `salary` column:

```
SELECT replace(salary, '0', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `translate()` as well:

```
select translate(salary, '0', '')
```

For one character, this is just like `replace()`.  However, this generalizes more nicely to multiple characters.  You can just list the characters instead of nesting calls to `replace()`.